# How to combine array element?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and still learning python.

I'm trying to combine 2 array, let's say it's `x=['a','b','c']` and `y=['1','2','3','4']`. How do i get `combined=['a1','b2','c3','a4']`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) + [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> x = ['a','b','c']
>>> y = ['1','2','3','4']
>>> [a + b for a, b in zip(cycle(x), y)]
['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'a4']
```

As pointed out in the comments by [@SanV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662022/how-to-combine-array-element/#comment98012249_55662040), to handle different sized lists you can use this function:

```
def zip_lists(x, y):
    if len(x) > len(y):
        y = cycle(y)

    elif len(x) < len(y):
        x = cycle(x)

    return [a + b for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

Which works like this:

```
>>> zip_lists(['a','b','c'], ['1','2','3','4'])
['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'a4']
>>> zip_lists(['a','b','c', 'd', 'e'], ['1','2','3','4'])
['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'e1']
>>> zip_lists(['a','b','c', 'd'], ['1','2','3','4'])
['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4']
```

Comment: very nice!  I gotta learn more about itertools one of these days! - kinda forgot about zip() too...knew there was something that did that.

Comment: @RoadRunner what if len(x) > len(y), then we need to cycle on y.  one could do list comprehensions with if/else but is there a more elegant way?